# TypeScript: How to use `resolveJsonModule` flag without emitting `.json` files?

Tags: json, typescript

I need to have following structure (previously I have had it, before updating of `tsconfig`):

- app (folder which includes only ts files)

  - ...
  - *.ts
- dist (output for js files as compiled ones)

  - ...
  - *.js
- data (folder for any data which is not a code)

  - data1.csv
  - data2.json
  - ...

Updated `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": [
    "app"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

**Before:** When I didn't use `resolveJsonModule` flag , all data (all `ts` files) has been compiled and moved into `dist`

**Now:** When I'm adding `resolveJsonModule` flag, `dist` contains `app` folder where are located compiled JS files + contains `data` folder (containing json files)

**Question:**
*How can I stay with previous logic, when json files were not being moved into output?*

Answer (score 0):

seems like you do not need `resolveJsonModule` flag. I don't know why you're using that flag since you don't need `JSON` files to begin with.

Refer: (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm using this flag in order to have the type of imported `json` file. I didn't find another way to get TS type of json file on build stage.